# Properties of convex functions

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a convex function. Then show that
$$
\operatorname{det}\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
x & y & z \\
f(x) & f(y) & f(z)
\end{array}\right] \geq 0
$$
for all $x<y<z$.

Here I got the determinant as $(y-x)(f(z)-f(x))-(z-x)(f(y)-f(x))$

how to prove the +ve definiteness

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: you can write the determinant as $$(z - x)\left(t f(x) + (1-t) f(z) - f(y)\right)$$
where $y = t x + (1-t) z$.